# adding predecessor zeros to an integer without casts in bash

Tags: bash, shell

I have the following code which is supposed to rename all files in the current working directory to "basenameCOUNTextension", given as command line arguments.

```
base=$1
ext=$2
c=1
for file in *
do
  if [ c > 100 ]; then
    mid=$(printf "%03d" $c)
  elif [ c > 10 ]; then
    mid=$(printf "%03d" $c)
  else
    mid=$(printf "%03d" $c)
  fi
  if [ -e ./"$file$mid$ext" ]
  then
    continue
  fi
  mv "$file" "$base$mid$ext"
  ((c++))
done
```

This would  be an example of contents in a directory after a successful running of this script:

```
$ renumber 25thAnniversary jpeg
then the resulting files should have names like:
25thAnniversary001.jpeg, 25thAnniversary002.jpeg, 25thAnniversary003.jpeg, etc.
```

Handling the "001", "939", etc is my issue. I'm not sure if printf is the way to go or just some conditionals.

This is my compilation error:

```
renumber.sh: line 12: =c: command not found
mv: cannot move â(FILEPATH)â to ââ: No such file or directory
```

What's my problem? Line 12 doesn't seem like a syntax error to me, and I don't understand the mv error.

Comment: I would recommend an hour or two with [**Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide**](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The dollar sign is not used on the left side of `=` to assign variables in bash.

A dollar sign means to replace the variable with the value of that variable before evaluating the command.  So if `$mid` does not have a value yet, `$mid="c"` becomes `=c`, which does not have a valid built-in meaning, so bash looks for an executable named `=c` on the `$PATH`, and errors when it can't find one.

On the other hand, `c` is supposed to be a variable, not the plain string "c", so you seem to mean `$c`.

So you should have something more like `mid=$c` .

You might also consider simplifying this by using the shell builtin `printf` command to avoid the first `if` chain:

```
mid=$(printf "%03d" $c)
```

Comment: My main issue seemed to be I was using arithmetic operators in the "[ ]" type conditional. I should have been using the (( ))

Answer (score 2):

You don't use `$` to *assign* a variable in a shell script.  Also, `for file in` loops just over the strings you give it, not over a directory, so use `for file in *`.